# Joining line breaks with commas and Removing empty lines to line breaks in Notepade++

Tags: regex, notepad++, line-breaks, blank-line

I have a text file like this...

```
$index 57320   
$title The vertex-cover polynomial of a graph  
$time 1988  
$abstract In this paper we define the vertex-cover...  

$index 57321   
$title Locating stations on rapid transit lines  
$time 1978  

$index 57322   
$title Fast heuristics for large scale covering-location problems  
$time 1998  
$abstract We propose fast heuristics for large scale...  

$index 57323   
$title Efficient vector processing on dataflow supercomputer SIGMA-1  
$time 2001  
$abstract Efficiency in vector handling is the key to obtaining high...
```

I want to convert each `linebreak` into `comma` and in the same time each `emptyline` to `linebreak`. Whereas the output for example text should be like this(text shortened using "dots"...):

```
$index 57320,$title The vertex-cover...,$time 1988,$abstract In this paper...  
$index 57321,$title Locating stations on...,$time 1978  
$index 57322,$title Fast heuristics for...,$time 1998,$abstract We propose fast...  
$index 57323,$title Efficient vector...,$time 2001,$abstract Efficiency in...
```

I tried `\r\n` replaced with `,` and it works but how to simultaneously apply both operations for converting `linebreaks` to `comma` and `emptyline` to be used as `linebreaks` for obtaining the desired output.

Please help in this regard.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put find & replace into regex mode.

Find:

```
([^\r\n]+)\r\n
```

Replace with:

```
$1,
```

You can find this instead, to get rid of the trailing space on each line:

```
([^\r\n]+?) *\r\n
```

Comment: @Bailey--It Works fine but no commas inserted between values, it is showing spaces

Comment: @taufel The commas are added by the replace part, so _$1_ is the column value, but you add a comma after with _$1,_  .

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in two steps. First, replace all the linebreaks with commas, but only if they are not at the start of the line, and only if a `$` character follows:

```
(?<!^)[ \t]*\r?\n(?=\$)
```

Replace all these matches with `,`. Note the `[ \t]*` part used to clean up whitespace at the end of each line - I found that in the sample you posted; if it's not there in reality, you can omit that part. Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rT0fM7/1).

Then, replace all `(\r?\n){2,}` with `$1`.

Comment: @Tim--How to remove white line spaces, it is giving empty lines between each of four rows in notepad++

Comment: Yes, that's why you need a second step - see the last line of my answer. It is not possible to do both in a single regex.

Comment: @Tim--I have tried second step in notepad++ but it is not matching anything after 1st step

Comment: @Tim--I think Bailey's answer is more concrete, it is doing the trick in single step

Comment: @Taufel Right. I should be more careful when saying that something isn't possible :) (And you should upvote Bailey's answer).